# How to use multiple text styles in one paragraph?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app I have a large body of text. For better readability I’m planning to use different colours, fonts etc on different parts of it.
I can’t use RichText with TextSpans  because it’s not a header and my text isn’t static. Also I never really know how much of them I need for particular page.
Is there a way to do this in flutter? Like find a piece of text (maybe marked with symbols or something else), format it and show on the screen?

As I said RichText and TextSpan isn’t my option. Other than that I didn’t find anything to help with my problem.

Comment: Can you further explain why RichText with TextSpan doesn't work for you?  It looks like the perfect option.  If you have some sort of markup in your text, you may need to preprocess it, like HTML or Markdown.